# How to prove that if $a\equiv b \pmod{kn}$ then $a^k\equiv b^k \pmod{k^2n}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, lifting-the-exponent

What I have done is this:

$a\equiv b \pmod{2n}$,

$a=b+c\times2n$, for some $c$,

$a^2=b^2+2b\times c\times2n+c^2\times2^2n^2$,

$a^2-b^2=(b\times c+c^2n)\times4n$, then

$a^2\equiv b^2\pmod{2^2n}$.

I think that this is right: what I DON’T understand is how to generalize this to:

$a\equiv b\pmod{kn}\Rightarrow a^k\equiv b^k \pmod{k^2n}$.

Please give me a hint.

Comment: Hi @gurghet - I've migrated your question here as it has no direct relation to cryptography as is - so this is the best place to get a good answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since $a\equiv b\pmod{kn}$, we have
$$a=b+ckn$$
for some integer $c$. Now taking the $k$th power on both sides, we have
$$a^k=(b+ckn)^k.$$
By the binomial theorem, the right hand side is given by
$$(b+ckn)^k=b^k+\sum_{i=1}^k{k\choose i}(ckn)^ib^{k-i}.$$
For $i\geq 2$, it is clear that
${k\choose i}(ckn)^ib^{k-i}$ is divisble by $k^2n$. On the other hand, for $i=1$, we have
${k\choose i}(ckn)^ib^{k-i}=ck^2nb^{k-1}$, which is also divisble by $k^2n$. Therefore, by the above equality, we have
$$(b+ckn)^k=b^k+k^2nN$$
for some integer $N$. Combining all these, we have
$$a^k=(b+ckn)^k=b^k+k^2nN,$$
that is
$$a^k\equiv b^k \pmod{k^2n}.$$

Comment: Thanks but I’m not sure about the binomial theorem. Is that right? I think it misses a $b^{k-i}$ in the sum.

Comment: It works anyway! Thanks!

Comment: @gurghet: Yes, you are right! I missed the term $b^{k-i}$. See my edited answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Since

$a^k-b^k=(a-b)(a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\ldots b^{k-1})$

we need only prove that 
$a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\ldots + b^{k-1}$ is divisible by $k$. But since $a \equiv b \ (\text{mod} \ k)$ we see that

$ a^{k-1}+a^{k-2}b+\ldots + b^{k-1} \equiv a^{k-1}+a^{k-1}+\ldots +a^{k-1} \equiv ka^{k-1} \equiv 0 \ (\text{mod} \ k). $

Comment: This is  a special case of the proof of the **double root test** - as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint** $ $ It's a special case of: $ $ a root of a polynomial [is a **double root**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1139902/242) if the derivative vanishes.

Thus to prove that $\rm\ \ k\mid  a-b\ \Rightarrow\ k^2 \mid  a^k-b^k\ =\ (a-b)\ \dfrac{a^k-b^k}{a-b},\ $ it suffices to prove

that $\rm\,k\,$ divides the second factor $\rm\,g.\,$  Theorem $\Rightarrow\rm\, g\equiv\, (a^k)'\equiv \color{#c00}k\, a^{k-1}\equiv\,0 \pmod{\!\color{#c00}k}.\ $ **QED**

**Theorem** $\ $ For $\rm R$ a ring and $\rm\,f(x)\in R[x]\quad\! $ [**Universal Polynomial Derivative Formula**]

$$\rm\begin{align}\rm g(x,y)\ &=\rm\ \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\ \in\ R[x,y]\\[.3em]
 \Rightarrow\ \ \rm  g(x,x)\ &=\rm\ f'(x)\ \in\ R[x]\\[.5em]
 \Rightarrow \ \ \rm \frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}&\rm\equiv\, f'(x)\pmod{\! x-y} 
\end{align}\qquad\qquad$$

**Proof** $\ $ By $\rm\,R$-linearity of the derivative it suffices to verify it for  a monomial $\rm\ f(x) = x^k\,.$

$$\begin{eqnarray}{}\rm &\rm g(x,y)\ &=&\rm\ \frac{x^k-y^k}{x-y}\, =\ x^{k-1} + x^{k-2}\,y +\, \cdots\, + x\,y^{k-2} + y^{k-1}\\[.3em] 
\Rightarrow\ &\rm g(x,x)\ &=&\rm\ k\ x^{k-1} =\ f'(x)\quad\ {\bf QED}
\end{eqnarray}\qquad $$

**Remark** $ $ To elaborate on a subtlety mentioned in a comment, $\rm\,g(x,y)\in R[x,y]\,$ means that $\rm \,g(x,y)\,$ denotes a *polynomial* in the indeterminates $\rm\,x,y,\,$ whose coefficients lie in the ring $\rm\,R\,$ (recall that $\rm\,x-y\,$ divides $\rm\,f(x)-f(y)\,$ in $\rm\,R[x,y]\,$  by the *Factor Theorem*). Being a polynomial its value is well-defined for all values of $\rm \,x,y\,$ so we can "evaluate" it at $\rm\,y = x\,$ (as is exemplified by the concrete case $\rm\,f(x) = x^k$ used in the proof).

In effect we exploit properties of polynomial rings to *universally* cancel an "apparent singularity" *before* evaluating. In more complicated contexts this can lead to nontrivial simplifications, e.g. replacing more complicated topological arguments by trivial algebraic arguments, e.g. see the discussion of the purely algebraic proof of *Sylvester's determinant identity* [linked here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/689049/242).

**Corollary** $\rm\ \ (fg)' = fg' + f'g\quad $ **[Derivative Product Rule]**

$\begin{align}{\bf Proof}\rm\ \ \ \ \ \  \dfrac{f(x)g(x)-f(y)g(y)}{x-y}\, &\rm =\, f(x) \,\dfrac{g(x)-g(y)}{x-y} + \dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\, g(y)\\[.5em]
\rm \overset{\large \rm y\ =\ x}\Longrightarrow\ \  (f(x)g(x))' &\rm =\, f(x)\,g'(x) + f'(x)\,g(x)\ \ \ \text{by evaluating at }\rm y = x \end{align}$

Comment: It is worth emphasizing that $g(x,y)=\dfrac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}\in R[x,y]$ is NOT the imperative "take (f(x)-f(y)) and divide by (x-y)", but the polynomial in two variables (that's what "$\in R[x,y]$" means) which when multiplied by (x-y) results in f(x)-f(y) -- this is why g(x,x) is not undefined.

Comment: @VladimirSotirov Actually it does denote the result of that *polynomial* division. But evaluating it at "apparent singularities" requires that we compute the quotient *before* we evaluate it. I added a remark elaborating on this subtlety.

Comment: See also [LTE](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3847038/242).