# How to prove that r is a double root if and only if it is a root of a polynomial and of its derivative.

Tags: derivatives, roots

I don't know how to start the question. The title is self explanatory. How to approach and make a formal proof?

Answer (score 9):

**Hint** $\ $ Wlog, by a shift, assume the root is $\rm\: r = 0.$

Notice $\rm\ \ x^2\: |\ f(x)$

$\rm\ \iff\ \color{#c00}{x\ |\ f(x)}\ $ and $\rm\ x\ \bigg|\ \dfrac{f(x)}{x}$

$\rm\ \iff\ \color{#c00}{f(0)\! =\! 0}\ $ and $\rm\ x\ \bigg|\ \dfrac{f(x)\!-\!\color{#c00}{f(0)}}x\,
\left[\!\!\iff\!\! \color{#0a0}{\dfrac{f(x)\!-\!f(0)}x}\bigg|_{\,x\,=\,0} \!= 0\,\right]$

$\rm\ \iff\ f(0)\! =\! 0\ $ and $\rm\ \color{#0a0}{f'(0)}\! =\! 0$

Above we used the Polynomial [$\rm\color{#c00}{Factor}$ Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/738715/242) and [$\rm\color{#0a0}{Derivative}$ Formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101549/242).

**Remark** $\ $ It's often overlooked that many divisibility properties of *numbers* are specializations of this double-root criterion for (polynomial) *functions*, e.g. see my [answer here.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/101549/242), or below from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4095874/242).

Hint: a *conceptual* way: we seek  $\,\color{#c00}{47^2\mid f(47)}\,$ for $\,f(x) = (x\!+\!5)^{n+1} + ((n\!-\!1)x\!-\!5)(2x\!+\!5)^n$

But $\,f(0)=0=f'(0)\,$ so by the [double root test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127799/242) (or first two terms of the Binomial Theorem), it follows that $\,x=0\,$ is a double root so $\,f(x) = x^2 g(x)\,$ for $g$ a polynomial with integer coef's. Evaluating at $\,x=47\,$ yields $\,\color{#c00}{f(47)}= 47^2 g(47).\ $ **QED**

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** (a slightly different approach).

Suppose that $f(x)$ has $r$ as a root $m$ times ($m\geq 1$).  Then $f(x)=(x-r)^m g(x)$ for some polynomial $g(x)$ with $g(r)\not=0$.  What is $f'(x)$?  What has to be true about $m$ if $f'(r)=0$?

Comment: m(x-r)^m-1 *g(x) + g'(x) (x-r)^m  ?

I forgot to mention integration is not allowed.

Comment: Sorry, i just came out of an exam. I meant integration

Comment: Ah, well you don't need to integrate.  So, you have $f'(x)=m(x-r)^{m-1}g(x)+g'(x)(x-r)^m$.  Suppose $f'(r)=0$.  What has to be true about $m$?  And, on the other hand, if $m\geq 2$ (ie if $r$ is a root more than once), then why is $r$ a root of $f'(x)$?

Comment: (g'(x) (x-r) )/ g (x) = m

Comment: is it because once we differentiate when is greater or equal to 2 then the root is still multiplying g(x) ?

Comment: Why are you trying to solve for $m$?  No, no, no.  We have $f'(x)=m(x-r)^{m-1}g(x)+g'(x)(x-r)^m$.  What is $f'(0)$?

Comment: Er, my previous comment should've ended with "What is $f'(r)$?"  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to solve this and came across this question. This is my solution. I hope it helps.

Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree n and r is a root of $P(x)$ and its derivative.

$$P(x)=(x-r)Q(x)$$
$$P ^\prime(x)=(x-r)S(x)$$
where $Q(x)$ and $S(x)$ are also polynomials.
Based on the first equation, we can also write $$P ^\prime(x)=Q(x)+(x-r)Q^\prime(x)$$
For $x \neq r$
$$S(x)=\frac{P ^\prime(x)}{(x-r)}=\frac{Q(x)+(x-r)Q^\prime(x)}{x-r}$$
$$=\frac{Q(x)}{x-r}+Q^\prime(x)$$
$$=\frac{P(x)}{(x-r)^2}+Q^\prime(x)$$
$$\Rightarrow P(x)=(x-r)^2(S(x)-Q^\prime(x))$$
So, r is a double root of $P(x)$.

If r is a double root of $P(x)$, we have
$$P(x)=(x-r)^2T(x)$$
where $T(x)$ is a polynomial. We have
$$P^\prime(x)=2(x-r)T(x)+(x-r)^2T^\prime(x)$$
So, r is also a root of  the derivative of $P(x)$.