# if $ax^2+bx+c$ and $2ax+b$ expressions have a common divisor, then $ax^2+bx+c$ is a full square.

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials, gcd-and-lcm

if $ax^2+bx+c$ and $2ax+b$ expressions have a common divisor,  then $ax^2+bx+c$ is a full square.

I would like to prove this statement.

Thank you for any idea.

Comment: Hint:  note that the linear polynomial is the derivative of the quadratic.

Comment: Hint:  $\,x-r\,$ is common divisor implies $r$ is a double root by the [Double Root Test](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127799/242). This is a dupe so please delete it once it is clear to you. You should specify the coefficient ring.

Comment: This is false if the common divisor is a constant.

Comment: @Rivers Yes, but it is common abuse of language that "have a common divisor" means the common divisor is *nontrivial*, i.e. not a unit (invertible).

Answer (score 0):

One way to prove this fact is to use the resultant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant

The following theorem holds ($R(f,g)$ is the resultant of two polynomials):

**Theorem:** If $A$ is a UFD, $f,g\in A[x]$ have a common irreducible factor if and only if $R(f,g)=0$.

Clearly, if $f,g\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ have a common root then they have a common irreducible factor (the converse is not true in $\mathbb{R}$, it is true in $\mathbb{C}$, since it is an algebraically closed field), and so their resultant must equal zero: $R(f,g)=0$.

So, let's suppose that $f=ax^2+bx+c\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, with $a\neq 0$, and $f'=2ax+b\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ have a common factor. Their resultant must equal zero:

$$R(f,g)=\det\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & c\\ 
2a & b & 0\\ 
0 & 2a & b
\end{bmatrix}=-a(b^2-4ac)=0$$

So $\Delta=b^2-4ac=0$, and thus $f$ is a perfect square.

**Edit:** As said in the comments, the coefficients ring was not declared. I guessed $f,f'\in\mathbb{R}[x]$.