# What is this linear operator/matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a linear operator with its matrix in certain coordinates to be

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
  1       & 0           & 0           & \cdots & 0 \\
  0       & \frac{1}{2} & 0           & \cdots & 0 \\
  0       & 0           & \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & 0 \\
  \vdots  & \vdots      & \vdots      & \ddots & \vdots & \\
  0       & 0           & 0           & \cdots & \frac{1}{n}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

What is this linear operator? How could I construct it without referring to coordinates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course it could be any number of things, but one operator with this matrix is the one that assigns to every polynomial $p(x)$ of degree less than $n$ the polynomial $\frac1x\int_0^xp(t)\,\mathrm dt$.

Comment: That's exactly how I came to this operator in connection with http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142941/antiderivative-of-polynomials I just hoped that there is some other interpretation I could rely on.