# Prove if p is a prime number that does not divide a, then $a^{p^2}$ congruent to $a^p\mod p^2$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I tried to do proof by contradiction, so I started to do use real arbitrary numbers.  I decided I use p for prime still, but a being a multiple of p and by doing this, the statement is still true.  I tried it with p=3, a =6 or p=2 and a =6.  Anyways to solve it by contradiction or should I use another method

Answer (score 3):

You have

$$a^{p^2} - a^p =a^p(a^{p^2-p} -1) =$$ $$ a^p(a^{\phi(p^2)}-1)\equiv a^p(1-1) \pmod{p^2},$$

where Euler's theorem is used in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

[Recall](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/87383/how-to-prove-that-if-a-equiv-b-pmodkn-then-ak-equiv-bk-pmodk2n/101549#101549) $\ b\equiv a \pmod{\!m}\,\Rightarrow\,b^{\large m}\equiv a^{\large m} \pmod{\!m^{\large 2}}.\,$  Put $\,b=a^{\large p},\ m = p$

Comment: It's a special case of the polynomial **double root test** - as I explain in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

As by Fermat's little theorem $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$ for any integer $a$

$(a^p)^p\equiv( a)^p$

So, we don't need $p\nmid a$